# Linux Deploy, Kali и переключение в monitor mode

Tags: android, linux, kali-linux

Есть Xiaomi Mi A1 c Android 8.1 Lineage OS. На карте памяти есть Kali Linux поставленный через Linux Deploy.

У меня есть интерфейс wlan0 в режиме managed. 
Я создаю новый интерфейс
`iw dev wlan0 interface add mon0 type monitor`
Поднимаю интерфейс
`ip link set mon0 up`
Убиваю все процессы которые могут помешать
`airmon-ng check kill`
Таким образом убиваю процесс wpa_supplicant, но он сразу возрождается. Отключить wpa_supplicant я не могу, так как находусь в chroot. Пробую пропустить этот шаг
`airmon-ng start mon0`
Получаю ответ

```
    Found 1 processes that could cause trouble.
Kill them using 'airmon-ng check kill' before putting
the card in monitor mode, they will interfere by changing channels
and sometimes putting the interface back in managed mode

  PID Name
 4374 wpa_supplicant

PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy12   mon0        wcnss_wlan  Not pci, usb, or sdio


ERROR adding monitor mode interface: command failed: Invalid argument (-22)
```

Вот и всё. Вопрос - как правильно использовать monitor mode на Kali в chroot? На ноуте сложностей не вызывает, а через смартфон никак не выходит. Может быть мешает wpa_supplicant но я не знаю как его окончательно убить. Есть советы или гайды по этому случаю?